# Install pip without root but with the system's python

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install `pip` without `sudo`.
Reading the [Install Docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/), it appears to be possible to use `--user` to have it being installed in my `home` directory.
After uninstalling `pip` from the global scope I tried `python get-pip.py --user` and obtain the following error:
`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/wheel-0.29.0.dist-info'`

Checking the `Install Docs` I found the following notice:
`Be cautious if you're using a Python install that's managed by your operating system or another package manager. get-pip.py does not coordinate with those tools, and may leave your system in an inconsistent state.`

Can I install pip into my home with the casual Ubuntu `apt-get` python? Or do I also need to build python locally?

Comment: Install from [sources](https://github.com/pypa/pip). Clone the repo and run `python setup.py install --user`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As phd mentoined in the comment of my question, cloning pip and installing it via `python setup.py install --user` worked out fine.

Comment: This may have been an Ubuntu issue (Python version or so), since under arch everything worked out fine right from the beginning.